# JSDoc with tsd-jsdoc for higher-order functions has bad output

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, jsdoc, tsd-jsdoc

I am using this npm command to build types from jsdoc:

```
"build-types": "jsdoc -t node_modules/tsd-jsdoc/dist -r src -d ./dist"
```

For this function:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {number} a 
 * @returns {function(number): number}
 */
const add = a => b => a + b;
```

the output into types.d.ts is:

```
declare function add(a: number): (...params: any[]) => any;
```

instead of expected:

```
declare function add(a: number): (arg0: number) => number;
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong in my setup?

Comment: `add` is curried not higher-order and I guess you need to document each nested function separately.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt yes curried and higher-order in this context is equivalent. Yea I found that I can do it by defining the inner function through typedef or callback but because curried functions are quite common in my code its quite cumbersome.